# Sketch App for Mac Zooming reversed

Tags: macos, mac, mouse, zoom, sketchup

The definition of apple 'natural, scrolling is: 'content tracks finger movement'.

This means for scrolling, if finger goes DOWN, content goes down. 
For ZOOMING it means that if finger goes from USER to SCREEN, content is pushed away (ZOOM OUT) and if finger goes from SCREEN to USER content is pulled (ZOOM IN).

I bought a sketchApp License, I got a bad headache and finally I understood that the problem was the reversed behaviour of zooming that makes the program unusable.

Even if I de-select natural (that is not an optimal solution) in that case EVERYTHING will be reversed, except the zoom.

I ask 3 things:

1. To me looks unbelievable that this product arrived to version 53 without at least the possibility to reverse the zoom through settings. To me doesn't look like a big fix, someone can tell me if a solution can be keep asking and asking the customer service until they fix it?
2. Sketch except for this problem looks a good product, so I already searched some program to reverse specifically only the zoom and only for sketch but I didn't find any working properly or with instructions how to do it. Someone can help me suggesting me a program?
3. I ask a SketchApp users how they manage to use the program because I always need to zoom in and out with mouse so for me is impossible to use it. I also use Adobe where the zooming works accordingly with Apple definition so I cannot 'get used to it'

Comment: 1. can't be answered by anyone except Sketch. 2. is off-topic. 3. isn't a question.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I found the solution both for a normal mouse and Magic Mouse 1 or 2, thanks to Marc of "Smart Scroll" http://www.marcmoini.com/sx_en.html

So I explained him the problem and within a week he manage to fix the "Sketch" problem for all the types of mouses (including magic mouse)

If you use a normal mouse with scroll, you need to edit  "scroll weel +" while if you have magic mouse you need to edit "multi touch +"

In both cases, the only need you need to set is:

Settings for: "Sketck" >> so it will affect only sketch.

Then:

Reverse: "Y Axis" only with "Command"

and it works.

So only when you use Sketch and only when you press "command" the Y axis will be reversed (the zoom)